# Where can I see the source code for Python's random library?

Tags: python, random

I want to check how they implemented the methods containing the particular library.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for `random` module can be found at [`random.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py). But due to performance reasons some parts of the library is implemented in C
which can be found at [`randommodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c)